# Yii2: specific form field editable based on Role

Tags: php, acl, yii2

Well, I can restrict users `access permissions`(i.e. view, create, update or delete) to forms or views based on access control using `behaviors`.

But I wonder how I can restrict a specific user from editing some of the fields in the form i.e. allow specific fields is `read-only` for some users and `editable` by some users.

Can I provide any kind of access rule in the model or attach some rule in the `_form.php` itself.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it can be done easily as far ur requirement is concerned without resorting to any utilities.

Try this code:

```
$form->field($model,'field')->textInput(['disabled' => !\Yii::$app->user->can('admin')]);
```

you need to replace ur field name and `admin` with your user role. In the above example only `admin` can edit this field, for other users it will show as disabled or readonly.

That's it.

Comment: This works but it is insecure making it silly as hell. Nothing actually prevents the user from posting info to the form. Anybody can easily edit the HTML, make that input not disabled and post the form thus changing the value. If you want a secure way of doing this then you have to use this with model rules that will now allow the user to change that part of the model. Also any answer that tells you to hide the input is silly.

Comment: @MihaiP. - Can you show me how to implement in model rules. Thanks.

Comment: @MihaiP.- Criticising people and not offering a solution is the easiest thing in the world.

Comment: @Pawan I told you the solution: implement it in the model, but you always expect code so you do not have to do anything. Also you never do any research so no, I am not giving you code anymore. I just do not want people to come and consider this an actual good solution as you do.

Comment: @Joshi sorry for being a little rude, just that this is not an answer, making something disable only prevents a normal user from changing it. Anybody with any programming background will know how to get around this. The model solution involves either scenarios or some simple if in the rules function or other ways of creating the rules array.

Comment: I agree with @MihaiP. You can consider my answer, that is more secure.

Comment: The Poster wants it to be `readonly` or `disabled` and not absence of it.

Comment: @Ankit also the absence of a input does not make it more secure, If I know the application I can easily edit the HTML page and add the input and submit the form.

Comment: In that case there is custom validation

Answer (score 3):

Try this.

```
if(\Yii::$app->user->can('admin')) {
    $form->field($model,'field')->textInput();
}
```

In this case the input field will only appear if condition matches.

Comment: your code works with modification -`if((\Yii::$app->user->can('admin'))) {
    $form->field($model,'field')->textInput();
}`

Comment: yes, I only gave you sample. you have to modify according your need.

Comment: Dont like this answer. Basiclly anyone can insert data with injection.

Answer (score 2):

For exactly this case I've created my own class that extends `ActiveForm`. With the code below it's possible to add rules to a specific field for one or more roles. I use it like this in my forms:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'foo', [], [AccessUtil::USER_ROLE => RoleBasedActiveForm::INVISIBLE]) ?>
```

The Role Based Active Form will show a normal input field when you don't add any rules. It won't display anything if you say it should be invisible for a roles and it also supports read-only (UNEDITABLE).

```
class RoleBasedActiveForm extends ActiveForm {

    const VISIBLE = 0;
    const INVISIBLE = 1;
    const UNEDITABLE = 2;

    public function field($model, $attribute, $options = [], $rules = []) {
        $case = empty($rules) ? self::VISIBLE : $this->_validateRules($rules);

        switch ($case) {
            case self::VISIBLE:
                return parent::field($model, $attribute, $options);
            case self::INVISIBLE:
                return;
            case self::UNEDITABLE:
                return parent::field($model, $attribute, array_merge($options, [
                            'template' => '{label}' . $model->$attribute,
                ]));
        }
    }

    private function _validateRules($rules) {
        // validate and return a const
    }
}
```

This will do the form part. You will also have to do some validation after posting the values of course, to make sure someone hasn't modified the form. (changed read only to editable with the inspector or something)

Comment: Hi jagsler - I have tried to implement the code as per ur suggestion, but I am getting the error - `Class 'AccessUtil' not found`

Comment: AccessUtil is just my own utility thats holds `const` values for the roles I've defined. So i usually have something like `const USER_ROLE = 'user';` and `const ADMIN_ROLE = 'admin';` in here. I suppose you're going to store the user role somewhere? In my case the `AccessUtil::USER_ROLE` is just a link to the textual representation of the role. In validateRules you can check if the role the user has matches with this string.

Comment: Thanks Jagsler - Can you kindly share the utility as with my level of knowledge - I don't think I can create one.

Answer (score 0):

This is a better answer.  You put this in the validation either inline or as a separate function.

```
[[ 'input-name' ],
    function ($attribute, $params) {
        $user_role_array = Yii::$app->authManager->getRolesByUser(Yii::$app->user->getId());
        if( !array_key_exists( "Role Name", $user_role_array ) ) {
            $myOldA = ( $this->getOldAttribute( $attribute ) );
            if( $this->{$attribute} !== (string) $myOldA ) {
                $this->addError($attribute, "Please contact XXXXX to modify this option. The field has been reset.  You may now resubmit the form" );
                $this->{$attribute} = $myOldA;
            } //End of if attribute equals old attribute
        } //End of if array key exists
    }, 'skipOnEmpty' => false, 'skipOnError' => false ],
[Next Rule if inline validation]
```